# Float versus Logged values in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, nlp, probability, floating-accuracy

I am calculating relative frequencies of words (word count / total number of words). This results in quite a few very small numbers (e.g. *1.2551539760140076e-05*). I have read about some of the issues with using floats in this context, e.g. in this [article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/dont-store-that-in-a-float/)

> A float has roughly seven decimal digits of precision ...

Some suggest using logged values instead. I am going to multiply these numbers and was wondering

- In general, is the seven digit rule something to go by in Python?
- In my case, should I use log values instead?
- What bad things could happen if I don't -- just a less accurate value or straight up errors, e.g. in the multiplication?
- And If so, do I just convert the float with math.log() - I feel at that point the information is already lost?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just use `Decimal` (`from decimal import Decimal`) for precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article talks about the type `float` *in C*, which is a 32 bit quantity. The Python type `float` is a 64 bit number, like C's `double`, and therefore can store roughly 17 decimal digits (53 fractional bits instead of 24 with C's `float`). While that too can be too little precision for some applications, it's much less dire than with 32-bit floats.

Furthermore, because it is a *floating point* format, small numbers such as `1.2551539760140076e-05` (which actually isn't that small) are not inherently disadvantaged. While only about 17 decimal digits can be represented, these 17 digits need not be the first 17 digits after the decimal point. They can be shifted around, so to speak<sup>1</sup>. In fact, you used the same concept of *floating (decimal) point* when you give a number as a bunch of decimal digits times a power of ten (`e-5`). To give extreme examples, 1<sup>-300</sup> can be represented just fine<sup>2</sup>, as can 10<sup>300</sup> — only when these two numbers meet, problems happen (`1e300 + 1e-300 == 1e300`).

As for a log representation, you would take the log of all values as early as possible and perform as many calculations as possible in log space. In your example you'd calculate the relative frequency of a word as `log(word_count) - log(total_words)`, which is the same as `log(word_count / total_words)` but possibly more accurate.

> What bad things could happen if I don't -- just a less accurate value or straight up errors, e.g. in the multiplication?

I'm not sure what the distinction is. Numeric calculations can have almost perfect accuracy (relative rounding error on the scale of 2<sup>-50</sup> or better), but unstable algorithms can also give laughably bad results in some cases. There are quite strict bounds on the rounding error of each individual operation<sup>3</sup>, but in longer calculations, they interact in surprising ways to cause very large errors. For example, even just summing up a large list of floats can introduce significant error, especially if they are of very different magnitudes and signs. The proper analysis and design of reliable numeric algorithms is an art of its own which I cannot do justice here, but thanks to the good design of IEEE-754, *most* algorithms *usually* work out *okay*. Don't worry too much about it, but don't ignore it either.

---

<sup>1</sup> In reality we're talking about 53 *binary* digits being shifted around, but this is unimportant for this concept. Decimal floating point formats exist.

<sup>2</sup> With a relative rounding error of less than 2<sup>-54</sup>, which occurs for any fraction whose denominator isn't a power of two, including such mundane ones as 1/3 or `0.1`.

<sup>3</sup> For basic arithmetic operations, the rounding error should be half a unit in the last place, i.e., the result must be calculated exactly and then be rounded correctly. For transcendental functions the error is rarely more than a one or two units in the last place but can be larger.

Comment: this is a beautiful answer, thank you! I have a real short follow up, just out of curiosity: you write that "summing up a large list of floats can introduce significant error". How many items does a list need to be large enough for that to happen?

Comment: @patrick It depends on the values in the list. A pathological example can be constructed with three values: `[1e300, 1e200, -1e300]` should be 1e200 but `sum(...)` returns 0. Real data is rarely as extreme and it takes bigger lists to have. And of course, many large lists don't exhibit such problems at all (there's still rounding error but it's very reasonable). There are smarter summation algorithms that avoid these problems, such as [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) which exists in Python as `math.fsum` (and returns 1e200 for the above example).